# No easy way to add Tensorboard output to pre-defined estimator functions DnnClassifier?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorboard

I have been using the estimator interface in TF 1.3 including the creation of the data input function:

`training_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=training_data, y=training_label, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None)`

and building the NN:

`dnnclassifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=dnn_features,
    hidden_units=[1024, 500, 100],
    n_classes=2, 
    model_dir='./tmp/ccsprop',
    optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
      learning_rate=0.001,
      l1_regularization_strength=0.01
    ))`

and executing it

`dnnclassifier.train(input_fn=training_input_fn, steps=1500)`

After much searching I see no easy way to add tensorboard output without resorting to recreating the model from scratch and indicated here https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators

And even then I can find no good examples to follow that both create a simple dnnClassifier with tensorboard output. any guidance?

I have the basic model working but need to examine it much more closely for tuning eventually using experiments as well. Don't see how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here for an extended discussion on GH: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12974#issuecomment-339856673

This does the trick to get a full set of TB output from canned models:

```
dnnclassifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
  feature_columns=dnn_features,
  hidden_units=[1024, 500, 100],
  n_classes=2, 
  model_dir='./tmp/ccsprop',
  optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
    learning_rate=0.001,
    l1_regularization_strength=0.01),
  config=tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(save_summary_steps=10)
)
```

Note the last line and be observant of where you need parentheses!

Answer (score 3):

When calling `DNNClassifier.train`, it accepts `hooks` parameter, you can create a [SummarySaverHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/train/SummarySaverHook) and add it to `hooks`.

### Update

When add a metric (accuracy for example) into TensorBoard, you should flow several steps:

1. Define a `Tensor` which calculate the accuracy: `acc_op = ...`;
2. Add the `Tensor` into `tf.summary.scalar`: `tf.summary.scalar('acc', acc_op)`;
3. There can be multiple `tf.summary` in `tf.Graph`, so we define a `merge_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()` to get an `op` to merge all the metric `Tensor`s.
4. Add the merge_summary_op into a `summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter()`;
5. Add the `summary_writer` into a `SummarySaverHook` or call the `summary_writer` by your own code.

Comment: Any pointer to a sample implementation? Struggling with the doc..
tried to create >TBcall=tf.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=10, output_dir='./tb') get >>AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'SummarySaverHook'

Comment: I got it to take TBcall=tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=10, output_dir='./tb') but it needs one of scaffold or summary_op, which I don't know how to reference? (And I'd like to get the graph?)

Comment: So, further `TBcall=tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=10, output_dir='./tb', summary_op='accuracy')` and `dnnclassifier.train(input_fn=training_input_fn, steps=1500, hooks=TBcall) ` gives the error: `'SummarySaverHook' object is not iterable`

Comment: hooks should be a list, so hooks = [TBcall]

Comment: But how should the called object be constructed,? I'm getting "Fetch argument 'accuracy' cannot be interpeter as a tensor.. What arguments/functions are accessible in the canned DNN? (my last comment has my attempt.

Comment: try `TBcall=tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=10, output_dir='./tb', summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())`

Comment: that gives this error: Exactly one of scaffold or summary_op must be provided

Comment: It seems your update in the main answer would require writing the model from scratch rather than using the `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` class? Which was my original question.. Anyhow, posted to GH https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12974