# Plot sklearn training operation in real time

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

Say I have a sklearn training data:

```
features, labels = assign_dataSets() #assignment operation
```

Here the `feature` is a 2-D array, whereas `label` consists is a 1-D array consisting of values `[0,1]`

The classification operation:

```
f1x = [features[i][0] for i in range(0, len(features)) if labels[i]==0]
f2x = [features[i][0] for i in range(0, len(features)) if labels[i]==1]
f1y = [features[i][1] for i in range(0, len(features)) if labels[i]==0]
f2y = [features[i][1] for i in range(0, len(features)) if labels[i]==1]
```

Now I plot the said data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(f1x,f1y,color='b')
plt.scatter(f2x,f2y,color='y')
plt.show()
```

Now I want to run the fitting operation with a classifier for example SVC.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(features, labels)
```

Now my question is as support vectors are really slow, is there a way to monitor the decision boundary of the classifier in real-time (I mean as the fitting operation is occurring)? I know that I can plot the decision boundary after the fitting operation has occurred, but I want the plotting of the classifier to occur in real time. Perhaps with threading and running predictions of an array of points declared by a linespace. Does fit function even allow such operations, or do I need to go for a some other library?

Just so you know, I am new to machine-learning.

Comment: I don't think there is support for callback-like functionality needed to grab unfinished solutions. Keep in mind, that SVC is based on libsvm, which is wrapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scikit-learn has this feature, but it's is limited to a few classifiers from my understanding (e.g. `GradientBoostingClassifier`, `MPLClassifier`). To turn on this feature, you need to set `verbose=True`. For example:

```
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(verbose=True)
```

I tried it with `SVC` and didn't work as expected (probably for the reason *sascha* mentioned in the comment section). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251980/a-progress-bar-for-scikit-learn) is a different variation of your question on StackOverflow.

With regards to your second question, if you switch to `Tensorflow` (another machine learning library), you can use the `tensorboard` feature to monitor a few of metrics (e.g. error decay) in real time.

However, to the best of my knowledge SVM implementation is still experimental in `v1.5`. `Tensorflow` is really good when working with neural network based models.

If you decide to use a DNN for classification using `Tensorflow` then here is a discussion about implementation on StackOverflow: [No easy way to add Tensorboard output to pre-defined estimator functions DnnClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064056/no-easy-way-to-add-tensorboard-output-to-pre-defined-estimator-functions-dnnclas/46065066)

Useful References:

Tensorflow SVM (only linear support for now - v1.5): https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/SVM

Tensorflow Kernals Methods: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/kernel_methods

Tensorflow Tensorboard: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard

Tensorflow DNNClassifier Estimator: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier

Comment: Yes. First, make sure your Keras setup is running on Tensorflow. Then you can you `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` to do the same thing. There is already a StackOverflow question on the implementation. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112260/how-do-i-use-the-tensorboard-callback-of-keras)

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the typos. I think for NNs the speed heavily depends on the number of samples, number of training iterations and the total number of neurons.